# Special paste with javascript

Tags: javascript, paste

I need to interpret text copied from emails. Currently, the users copy the text of the email and paste it into an HTML text area. I already have a 90% solution, but here is one case that is stumping me. The data is stored in a table in the email. Here is one row of that data, which could easily have 50 rows or more, in a similar format:

```
<tr>
<td valign=3D"top" style=3D"background:white;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in">
<p class=3D"MsoNormal"><span style=3D"color:black">WI</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
<td valign=3D"top" style=3D"background:white;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in">
<p class=3D"MsoNormal"><span style=3D"color:black">BARABOO 53913</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
<td valign=3D"top" style=3D"background:white;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in">
<p class=3D"MsoNormal"><span style=3D"color:black">8:00</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
<td valign=3D"top" style=3D"background:white;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in">
<p class=3D"MsoNormal"><span style=3D"color:black">VAN</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
<td valign=3D"top" style=3D"background:white;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in">
<p class=3D"MsoNormal"><span style=3D"color:black">WI</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
<td valign=3D"top" style=3D"background:white;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in">
<p class=3D"MsoNormal"><span style=3D"color:black">8/29/2015</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
</tr>
```

This is an example of the sort of things I have to accomodate, although I actually want to accomodate a lot more.

When the user pastes that row, it turns into this:

```
WI


BARABOO 53913


8:00


VAN


WI


8/29/2015
```

Keep in mind that I am receiving many rows, so they all get run together. The number, order, and format of the columns are completely inconsistent, sometimes even within the same document.

If I could get this, I can use my already existing code to parse it:

```
WI BARABOO 53913 8:00 VAN WI 8/29/2015
```

But I have pretty much nothing to work with. If I had the raw HTML, I could parse it safely (It is never displayed), but I can't get it. Does anyone know how I can get this as raw HTML or some other coherent format? I doubt if it matters, but in most cases, the source of the copy will be MS Outlook.

edit: the whole goal is to make this machine-parsable. I don't need help with the parsing, I have that covered. I just need something useful to parse.

Comment: can you use jquery??

Comment: Yes, I can use jquery.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the pasted HTML maintained if you replace your text area with a "contentEditable" element, such as a `<div>`. Try this for example, it will alert the html "source" you paste into it:

```js
var paste = document.getElementById('paste');
paste.onpaste = function() { setTimeout(function() { alert(paste.innerHTML); }, 1); };
```

```css
#paste {
  width:200px;
  height:60px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="paste" contentEditable="true"></div>
```

Note that the content is available ***after*** the `onpaste` event fires, so use a timeout.

Comment: If I run your example, it alerts [Javascript Application]. If I run it on my own page, it alerts undefined. If I replace the alert with a console log, it logs an empty string.

Comment: Ok, now this is interesting. If I paste the whole table it works, if I paste just part of it, it does not. My assumption is that it doesn't like malfomed HTML. I unfortunately cannot assume that the users paste everything.

Comment: I guess it's not as widely compatible as I thought, it works perfectly on chrome, even chrome mobile. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Latest firefox on Linux

Comment: I guess the undefined / empty string is an odd timing issue. Do you see anything inside the target div after the alert? If you do, try increasing the timeout duration, maybe 150ms would be unnoticeable.

Comment: No, if I copy only part of the table, absolutely nothing shows up either in the alert or in the target. If I copy the whole table, it all works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the [paste event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/paste), for Chrome and Firefox, may have a `clipboardData` property of type [DataTransfer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer). That has a `getData` method that takes a content type, so you may be able to do this to check if the content is HTML:

```
textArea.addEventListener('paste', function (e) {
  var html = e.clipboardData && e.clipboardData.getData('text/html');
  if (html) {
    // handle HTML table logic
  }
});
```

**Update**:

Interestingly, IE has a [beforepaste](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536905(v=vs.85).aspx) event which looks like it has a similar `clipboardData` object, so maybe you can handle that browser using this technique.

Comment: I like what you have so far. It works great on firefox and chrome. I would like to support IE as well, but it's not working (html is undefined). Any chance there is a solution for that as well? If not, I can have my current solution as a fallback, but I'd rather not do that.

Comment: Looks like there's a similar `beforepaste` event for IE you could hook into that _does_ have `clipboardData.getData`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Jquery solution.

```
 $('#txtArea').on('paste', function() {

    setTimeout(function () { 
    var txt=$(this).val();
     $(this).val(txt.replace(/\s+/g, ' ')); 
    }, 100);



 })​;
```

Comment: `$(this).val()` will give the value of the textarea *before* the paste. Along with that `.trim()` will only affect the beginning and end of a string.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek  I've updated the answer.Thank you !

Comment: All you did was remove the new lines. I need it to have some sort of structure. Also, 2 easily corrected syntax errors: $(this).val(txt ... ) should be in the timeout and the value of this is not transferred into the timeout function, so you need to store it to a variable such as self first.

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this is to simply format the data yourself when it is pasted. For example, you can replace the newlines with spaces, then replace the many spaces with a single space. Then set the `textarea` with that new value:

```
text.replace(/\r|\n|\n\r/g, ' ').replace(/ +(?= )/g,'');
```

Then you would, have this in a `onpaste` event. Make `text` be the clipboard contents, and finally set the `textarea` to the new text:

```
document.getElementById("text").addEventListener('paste', function (e) {
    var text = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
    text = text.replace(/\r|\n|\n\r/g, ' ').replace(/ +(?= )/g,'');

    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("text").value = text;
    }, 10);
});
```

[**Here is a fiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/n6x5mhp7/). Take the content and paste it into the text area, it will be changed to `"WI BARABOO 53913 8:00 VAN WI 8/29/2015"`.

Comment: All you did was take it and put it all on one line. What happens if there are two rows in the table? or 20? or 30? There still isn't any way to group the fields together into records.